# bottomNavigationBar do what I want only while hot reloading

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to have a static bottom bar for my app.
This bar should content the hour of a device in the middle, and the temperature read by another device on the right side.

[image: here is an example of what I want]

**My problem is just about the positioning/sizing.**

When I start it (with android studio, on real or virtual device), it doesn't work : the preview is not what I excepted, the dimensions I choose seem to have changed.

[image: preview when I start on a device]

But when I hot-reload it, it becomes exactly what I want like this :

[image: while hot-reloading]
The problem is that the final app is not the hot-reloaded one ..

I may have identify the problem,
I use a MediaQuery.of(context).size and a builder to obtain the context in order to fit with all the devices considering the size. This solution must be a dirty one but I don't find anything else..

Here is my code, hope the situation is clear...

```
return new MediaQuery(
    data: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.window),
    child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return  new Builder(
              builder: (
                  context) {
                return
                new MaterialApp(
                    home: new DefaultTabController(
                      length: 6,
                      child: Scaffold(
                        bottomNavigationBar:



                          new Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: new Container(
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width* 2/3,
                                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                      child: new Row(
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  new Expanded(child: new Container(
                                                    color : Colors.yellow,
                                                    child: new Text('22 : 22' ),
                                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                  )),
                                                  new Expanded(child:new Container(
                                                    color: Colors.pink,
                                                    child: new Text(' 37.8 °C'),
                                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.02),
                                                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                                  ))
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                    ),


                          ),
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Perhaps you are not using `setState(...)` when you update model values? I didn't fully dig into your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Stack` and position one of the widget absolute over the other one:

```
new Stack(
    children: <Widget> [
        new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget> [
                new Text(time),
            ],
        ),
        new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget> [
                new Text(temperature)
            ],
        ),
    ],
),
```

where `time` & `temperature` are variables that were set within the state ([Stateful Widgets)](https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/). Then just include it in `bottomNavigationBar`.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually added my previous code in a `StatelessWidget` and call it in the  `bottomNavigationBar` field of the `Scaffold` :  it does the job.

And I call MediaQuery.of(context) within the `StatelessWidget` created

Thank you.